# Youtube fancybox will not work

Tags: html, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am currently trying to make a fancybox with a youtube video inside it. I currently have a couple more fancyboxes on the page but can not seem to get this fancybox to work,the other fancyboxes have the class of fancybox-iframe or fancybox depending on the content if this is any help.

Below is the link that I want to add fancybox to.

```
<a href="http://youtu.be/krlR2-YGk4sI" target="_blank"><span class="cta floatL">through the eyes of a bigsmile advert</span><span class="playIco floatL"></span></a>
```

This is the iframe that I am putting into my fancybox. Can somebody please help me?

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/krlR2-YGk4sI?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to place your video inside an `iframe`. The only html you need is the link to your video like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://youtu.be/krlR2-YGk4sI" target="_blank">Open youtube</a>
```

**Notice** the class `fancybox` in the `<a>` tag (you can use any other *class* name, just make sure you bind the correct selector to fancybox)

Then include the fancybox **media helper** in your page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/fancybox/files/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

... and add the `helpers` media API option to your custom script like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hR5Wk/)</kbd>